# create query using webservice api for Rally

Tags: rally

I am trying to write a query in Ruby to insert a user story in Rally using WSAPI. I read through https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/.I looked it up and found that wsapi has a create() method, but I am not aware of its signature. I know it uses PUT/Post method for creation, but I just need an example to understand how to write create queries. Does anyone know of any useful resource to know more about this? I have all my code ready, just need information about writing "create" queries using Rally's WSAPI.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a full directory of Ruby REST examples in the Github Repository for RallyRestToolkitForRuby:

https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby/tree/master/examples

This create example may be of particular interest. It's for a Defect, but the same logic would apply to Stories:

[04-create-defect.rb](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby/blob/master/examples/04-create-defect.rb)